# org export with tikz entries

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I would like to use orgmode for preparing exam questions.
For tex-template I am using tikz which includes some text entries e.g. for the title and subtitle.

The tex part for tikz looks e.g. like:

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{every node}=[font=\sffamily\upshape]
\draw(-2.76,1.21)rectangle(17.5,1.91)node[midway,black]{TIKZ_MODULE};
\draw(-2.76,0.51)rectangle(17.5,1.21)node[midway,black]{TIKZ_SUBMODULE};
\draw(-2.76,-0.19)rectangle(4,0.51)node[midway,left]{Name:\hspace*{2cm}};
\draw(4.0,-0.19)rectangle(9,0.51)node[midway,left,black]{Matr.-Nr.:};
\draw(9.0,-0.19)rectangle(13,0.51)node[midway,left,black]{Blatt:\thepage / \pageref{LastPage} };
\draw(13.0,-0.19)rectangle(17.5,0.51)node[midway,black]{TIKZ_SHORT_NAME};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The string `TIKZ_MODULE`, `TIKZ_SUBMODULE` and `TIKZ_SHORT_NAME` should be replaced by the corresponding orgmode entries, see below:

```
#+TITLE: title
#+SUBTITLE: subtitle
#+AUTHOR:  author
#+DATE: Sept 2021
#+INSTITUTE: department
#+TIKZ_MODULE: module
#+TIKZ_SUBMODULE: submodule
#+TIKZ_SHORT_NAME: short_name
```

Do you have a hint how this can be done?

It is also possible that the I use the `TITLE` and `SUBTITLE` for the `TIKZ_MODULE` and `TIKZ_SUBMODULE`, but I am not sure, if this is easier.

Actually I am sure, that this is already described somewhere, but I do not know which words describe my question for searching.

Comment: I think this can already help, I will check https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/add-new-header-variable-in-org-mode-document-and-use-it-in-latex-export

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a library of babel like approach. Here I setup a src block named tikz in a section that is not exported. You could put this in another file, and load it via library of babel (see `org-babel-lob-ingest`.

Then this line `#+call: tikz[:eval t]()` inserts that text at export time, or you can execute it and see it when writing the document.

```
#+TIKZ_MODULE: module
#+TIKZ_SUBMODULE: submodule
#+TIKZ_SHORT_NAME: short_name


#+call: tikz[:eval t]()


* lob                                                              :noexport:

#+name: tikz
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results latex
(let ((kws (org-collect-keywords '("TIKZ_MODULE"
                   "TIKZ_SUBMODULE"
                   "TIKZ_SHORT_NAME"))))
  (format "\\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\\tikzset{every node}=[font=\\sffamily\\upshape]
\\draw(-2.76,1.21)rectangle(17.5,1.91)node[midway,black]{%s};
\\draw(-2.76,0.51)rectangle(17.5,1.21)node[midway,black]{%s};
\\draw(-2.76,-0.19)rectangle(4,0.51)node[midway,left]{Name:\\hspace*{2cm}};
\\draw(4.0,-0.19)rectangle(9,0.51)node[midway,left,black]{Matr.-Nr.:};
\\draw(9.0,-0.19)rectangle(13,0.51)node[midway,left,black]{Blatt:\\thepage / \\pageref{LastPage} };
\\draw(13.0,-0.19)rectangle(17.5,0.51)node[midway,black]{%s};
\\end{tikzpicture}"
      (cadr (assoc "TIKZ_MODULE" kws))
      (cadr (assoc "TIKZ_SUBMODULE" kws))
      (cadr (assoc "TIKZ_SHORT_NAME" kws))))
#+END_SRC
```